# Looping actions/events in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a simple open/close dropdown kind of thing. Something like

```
-Point 1
   content
+Point 2
+point 3
```

This is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #drop-down
        {
            display:none;
            margin-left:30px;
        }
        .closed
        {
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        .opened
        {
            cursor:pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3 class="closed">+ First Line</h3>
        <div id="drop-down">
            <p>Random content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="closed">+ First Line</h3>
        <div id="drop-down">
            <p>Random content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="closed">+ First Line</h3>
        <div id="drop-down">
            <p>Random content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $('.closed').click(function(){
        $(this).nextAll('#drop-down').css("display","block");
        $(this).removeClass('closed');
        $(this).addClass('opened');
    });
    $('.opened').click(function(){
            $(this).nextAll('#drop-down').css("display","none");
            $(this).removeClass('opened');
            $(this).addClass('closed');
    });
</script>
</html>
```

This opens the dropdown. But doesn't close it. So I changed my code like

```
<script>
    $('.closed').click(function(){
        $(this).nextAll('#drop-down').css("display","block");
        $(this).removeClass('closed');
        $(this).addClass('opened');
        $('.opened').click(function(){
            $(this).nextAll('#drop-down').css("display","none");
            $(this).removeClass('opened');
            $(this).addClass('closed');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now open and close works but only once. If I continue nesting like this, it works till the level I nest. How to make this work without continuous nesting. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: IDs should be unique and must not repeat on your HTML

Comment: What if the number of dropdowns are dynamic? And why does the opening works and closing doesnt work in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use only below code,wil work

```
<script>
    $('.closed').click(function(){
        $(this).nextAll('#drop-down').toggle(); 


    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific code, the problem is that the events are not being bound for *new* elements.

When you bind using `.click`, it will only bind the event for elements currently in the DOM.

That is why it works when you nest event bindings. Technically you could get this to work (not efficiently) by rebinding your `click` events after each click, which is what you've done with your nesting.

You need to use `.on` instead to trigger the event for any new elements:

```
$(document).on("click", ".closed", function () {
    $(this).nextAll('.drop-down').css("display", "block");
    $(this).removeClass('closed');
    $(this).addClass('opened');
});
```

Also, you should be using a `class` instead of an `id` for your selector. An `id` should always be unique. Since all dropdowns share a common quality, you should use a `class` instead.

[Take a look at this jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/eFd38/)

Answer (score 0):

As comments above have stated, ID's are unique and can't be used twice. Next if you're changing the class dynamically you'll need to use delegation. Also your javascript should be in a document ready.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h3 class="closed">+ First Line</h3>
    <div class="drop-down">
        <p>Random content</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <h3 class="closed">+ First Line</h3>
    <div class="drop-down">
        <p>Random content</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <h3 class="closed">+ First Line</h3>
    <div class="drop-down">
        <p>Random content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.closed', function(){
        $(this).nextAll('.drop-down').css("display","block");
        $(this).removeClass('closed');
        $(this).addClass('opened');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.opened', function(){
        $(this).nextAll('.drop-down').css("display","none");
        $(this).removeClass('opened');
        $(this).addClass('closed');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

add `accordian` class and change `id="drop-down"` to `class="drop-down"` (because you should not change same id multiple times) and so do change in `drop-down` css definition.
HTML

```
<div>
        <h3 class="accordian closed">+ First Line</h3>
        <div class="drop-down">
            <p>Random content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="accordian closed">+ First Line</h3>
        <div class="drop-down">
            <p>Random content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 class="accordian closed">+ First Line</h3>
        <div class="drop-down">
            <p>Random content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.accordian ').click(function(){
     $('.accordian ').removeClass('opened').addClass('closed');
     $('.drop-down').hide();
     $(this).addClass('opened').removeClass('closed');
     $(this).next('.drop-down').show();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.drop-down
        {
            display:none;
            margin-left:30px;
        }
        .closed
        {
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        .opened
        {
            cursor:pointer;
        }
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/315/)